# Standard Order for Siddur Printing

Tags: prayer-book

I have noticed over the years that the order of the pagination of siddurim seems somewhat standard.

For example:

- Birchot Hashachar
- Shacharit (chol)
- Minchah (or page list for tefillot minchah)
- Maariv (chol) or tefillot Shabbat

However, despite the standardisation of the order of complete services, I have not been able to figure out some of the general positions of alternate and additional tefillot which are occasionally added (e.g. Rosh Chodesh).

What is the general table of contents, per consultation with multiple siddurim? (either of one nusach or in general)

Comment: I don't understand what you hope people to help you with. [I know you have access to _sidurim_.](/search?q=user%3A4504+is%3Aq+[sidur]) The best anyone can do is look in _sidurim_ and see what seems to be the popular order. Why can't you do it? The downvote button here says "This question does not show any research effort": −1.

Comment: @msh210, I intend to create an answer when I have access to some of my siddurim in a wiki. I can start that now, although it will not be as thorough as it will be later

Answer (score 0):

The siddurim I'm familiar with typically follow an arrangement like the following.

- Children's prayers
- Birchot HaShachar
- Shacharit (Pesukei d'zimrah for shabbat might be interpolated here)
- Additional tefillot said by some (alternately in the back)
- Minchah (chol) or page list for Ashrei, Amidah, Nefillat appayim, Aleinu
- Maariv (chol) (alternately listed after Shabbat tefillot)
- Seder L'leil Shabbat
- Maariv (Shabbat/y"t)
- Kiddush L'leil Shabbat
- Zemirot
- Shacharit (Shabbat/Y"T)
- Musaf (" ")
- Kiddush L'yom Shabbat
- Zemirot
- Minchah (Shabbat/Y"T)
- Pirkei Avot (and Barchi Nafshi)
- Seudah Shelishit and additions for Motzei Shabbat
- Havdalah
- Musaf for Rosh Chodesh (and sometimes for Shabbat R"Ch)
- Hallel
- Amidah for the Shalosh Regalim
- Musaf for "   "

Comment: In many siddurim Birkas Hamazon, Birchos Henehenim, the Marriage Ceremony, Bris Miloh and Pidyon Haben follow shacharis.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, In many older siddurim, as well as those used by the United Synagogue and Israeli publishers, they seem to often be in the back. This wiki certainly leaves space for alternate paginations though

Comment: Singer's (United Synagogue) prayer book was modelled on the Avodas Yisroel of Baer who had bentsching at the back.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, SA"Y was also modeled on the works of R' Wolf Heidenheim

Comment: Many _sidurim_ IME have _mincha_ and _maariv_ on the same pages: "_Ashre_" atop the _birchos k"sh_ with a shared _amida_.

Comment: _Halel_ is usually IME before _musaf_ of _r"ch_ rather than after it.

Comment: @msh210, I've only seen minchah/maariv printed together in one siddur, a horribly offset affair which is kept by the local sefarim shop for their daily minchah minyanim

Comment: After _Shabas_ stuff is often IME _motz"sh_ stuff like "_V'yiten l'cha_" and _kidush l'vana_ and "_Amar Hashem l'Yaakov_".

Comment: V'gam lecha, for Hallel and musaf r"ch, I've seen both.